# Jquery each function for td in tr

Tags: jquery, function, parent-child, each

I basically want to find every second eq(1) td's val for each tr in the tbody ...

```js
var distancefrom = x;
var distanceto = y;

$("#village_troup_list tbody tr").each(function () 
{
    var allo = $("#village_troup_list tbody tr").find('td').eq(1).val();
});
```

... and then:

```js
if (distancefrom <= [theValueImGetting] <= distanceto) 
{
    // run something for the tr this td is in
}
```

I tried `$(this)`, but it didn't do anything, so I'm guessing that's not the right approach.

***How could I do this in a neat manner?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var trs = $('#village_troup_list tr td:nth-of-type(2)').map(function() {
    var val = $(this).text();
    if(val >= distancefrom && val <= distanceto)
        return $(this).parent();
});

trs.each(function(i, tr) {
    // run something for the tr which second td element's value meets the criteria
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Never would've thought about something like this (never used it too), this'll be usefull for other stuff as well. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each("#village_troup_list tbody tr",function() {
    alert( $(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
     // or may be this one
     alert( $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text());
})
```

Comment: This also doensn't seem to work. I'm not sure why nothing is working... This doesn't even give alert btw so I don't think this can work? :x

Comment: The question has already been answered, do you still want the html? If so I'll put it in a fiddle for you

Comment: Ya it will be great if you can put it in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you can use $(this) instead.

```
$("#village_troup_list tr").each(function(item,i) {
    alert($(this).find('td').eq(1).text())
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NLhzc/ is working here

Comment: Unfortenatly, this gives me an undefined alert for every tr :(

Comment: Tried both text and val, though I'm sure my code is correct since I alert tested it for the firs tr in tbody, ant it worked with val(). I just can't get it to work for every tr...